# Central limit theorem is expected, but variance is apparently sublinear? So?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

In *[Perplexing Problems in Probability](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817640934)*, the following statement about first passage percolation (FPP) on $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ is made. See e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203262.pdf) of Benjamini, Kalai and Schramm, where they quote from the section on FPP in the works of Kesten...

> Novice readers might expect to hear next of a central limit theorem
>   being proved,” writes Durrett, describing Kesten’s results, “however
>   physicists tell us...that in two dimensions the standard
>   deviation...is of order $|\mathbf{v}|^{1/3}$"

They are saying that geodesics on the lattice from the origin to a point $\mathbf{v}$ have a length with variance which converges to $C|\mathbf{v}|^{2/3}$ as $|\mathbf{v}| \to \infty$

But, a central limit theorem does apply. Do the novices simply miss the fact that the variance is non-trivial? Is there no such thing as a central limit theorem here?

Why would you *not* expect a central limit theorem to be proved for the geodesic length distribution, simply due to this sublinear variance?

Comment: Ok I will move it there

Comment: Actually, it fits here. The short answer to the question is that by the statement, Durrett really meant "CLT with variance $n^{1/2}$", and the exponent $1/3$ already tells you that something unusual is going on.  In fact, one does not expect a Gaussian limit (as in "CLT") but rather a Tracy-Widom limit. In the case of exponential weights, a version of this result is proved by Johansson (Theorem 1.2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9903134.pdf). See also https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910146.pdf for a related result and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.00729.pdf for a recent perspective and references.

Comment: I see - my apologies to the OP for a hasty reading.

Comment: Thank you all. So, the travel time is Tracy-Widom. What about the transversal deviations of the geodesics? Is the distribution also Tracy-Widom?